# Formatting string with RegExp to set delimiter

Tags: ruby, regex, delimiter, gsub

I'm trying to format a string as follows

Ensure all of numbers use dashes for delimiters.
 Example: 480.01.4430 and 480014430 would both be 480-01-4430.

this is what I have come up with so far, but I can't understand why it doesn't work

```
def format_ssns(string)
  ssn = string[/\d{9}/]
  ssn.gsub(/\d{9}/, /\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}/)
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's strange that you're not getting an exception: The second argument to [gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) is required to be a String (or something that can be converted to a String), not a regexp.

Here's a working example:

```
ssn = '123456789'
ssn.gsub(/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{3})/, '\1-\2-\3')
# => "123-45-6789"
```

There are three groups of digits in the original string.  We enclose each group in parentheses.  Each pair of parentheses creates a *match group*.  In the replacement string, we use `\1` to include the first match group, `\2` to include the second match group, and `\3` to include the third match group, with dashes between them.

Comment: `/\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}/` responds to `to_s`, which is probably why its slipping through.

Comment: @the - In 1.8.7, 1.9.3, and 2.0.0, If I pass a regexp in as the second parameter to gsub, I get a TypeError exception.  Is the OP using Rails with yet another odd monkey-patch at work?

Comment: Maybe the OP isn't calling the method in question.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about anything in the string, than is not a digit, you can strip everything else and format as you want:

```
string.gsub(/\D/, '').gsub(/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "\\1-\\2-\\3")
```