# Adding / Replacing Delimiters with Regex

Tags: ruby, regex, delimiter

I'm currently looking to separate any 9 digit integer by the specific delimiter "-" after the 3rd digit and the 5th digit.  Ie:

999999999 would be 999-99-9999

I am able to insert delimiters using regex group matching and gsub, however I am *not* able to remove any existing delimiters and replace with the desired "-", using:

```
 def format_ssns(string)
  string.gsub(/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, '\1 -\2-\3')
```

end

I found basically the exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424323/formatting-string-with-regexp-to-set-delimiter), which was helpful in reinforcing that the thought pattern is correct.  Yet even using this exact same code, if one were to call the method using "999.99.9999" it would not replace the existing delimiter with a dash.

Is there a different expression I should be using to replace one with another (though in looking [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub), [here](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/regexes/) and --*well I had more than 2 links of reference but not enough reputation to post them --* I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to be using gsub).

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with doing it in two steps.  Use one regex to remove old delimiters or any other cruft, and then use the one you showed to add the correct ones back in.

Comment: I agree with @Andy, just insert `.gsub(/\D/,'')` between `string` and `.gsub....` Doing it in two steps simplifies testing. In a real app (I assume this is an exercise), you'd probably want to check that the string contains either nine digits or eleven characters with digits and non-digits in the appropriate positions. Aside: you need to remove the space in `'\1 -\2-\3'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a placeholder character between your capture groups

```
def format_ssns(string)
  string.gsub(/(\d{3}).?(\d{2}).?(\d{4})/, '\1 -\2-\3')
end
```

Notice the `.?`s - they capture anything that might be already in between the numbers (including nothing)

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to `/(\d{3})\D?(\d{2})\D?(\d{4})/` to include potential delimiters. `\D` means not a number. If you want a precise list of delimiters you could use a character class like `[-./]?` to allow delimiters `-`, `.`, `/` and nothing at all.

Using `/^(\d{3})\D?(\d{2})\D?(\d{4})$/` would be better if the number is the only thing in your string. Otherwise, some sort of logic to know what are the boundaries of the number would be good to avoid matching 999999999999999999999.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the fact that gsub takes a block:

```
add_separators = -> x { x.insert(5, '-').insert(3, '-') }
p 'string 123456789'.gsub(/\d{9}/, &add_separators) #=> "string 123-45-6789"
```